# Добавить ссылку на проект в Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые! У меня такой вопрос. Я до этого писал в Visual Studio, а тут решил написать что-нибудь под андроид. Установил sdk, установил Eclipse, но после Visual Studio в Eclipse мне многое кажется непривычным. Скажем, у меня есть проект, представляющий собой андроид-приложение, клиент то есть. Также я хочу добавить проект, содержащий бизнес-логику. Но не очень пока что понимаю, как это сделать. То есть в Visual Studio я бы сделал так: создал бы android-проект, затем создал бы проект типа class library и описал бы в нем бизнес-логику. Затем добавил бы ссылку на этот проект в андроид-приложение с помощью Add Reference. Но пока не очень пойму, как это сделать в Eclipse. То есть если в Vuisual Studio у меня был очень простой и удобный способ добавлять ссылки на другие проекты или библиотеки (причем стандартные .NET библиотеки были в виде специального списка), то в Eclipse я не понимаю, как это сделать.

И еще вопрос. В Visual Studio проекты объединяются в решения. Файлы проекта имеют расширение csproj, а файлы солюшнов - расширение sln. А как это все сделано в Java и Eclipse?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:
1) создать новый проект;
2) импортировать проект с логикой;
3) правой кнопкой по *новому* проекту, **properties > configure build path > add** добавить проект с логикой;
4) правой кнопкой по проекту с *логикой*, **properties > configure build path** и поставить галочку **As library**.
И да, не забудьте, по очереди почистить и пересобрать каждый проект **отдельно**.